# Использование return и bool

Tags: c++, return, bool

Мне нужно написать программу, которая проверяет условие для всех элементов массива. Если условие выполняется, то выводит yes, а если нет, то false. Я создал две функции. Одна из них проверяет условие, и если оно выполняется, то возвращает true, а если нет, то false. Но почему-то мне всегда выводит yes, даже если функция, проверяющая условие, возвращает false. Почему так? Я же правильно понимаю, что запись if (isheap) - это то же самое, что и написать if (isheap == true)? Т.е. если функция isheap вернула значение true.

````
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;



bool isheap(int arr[], int n, int i);
void withdraw();


int main()
{

    int array[] = { 1, 0, 1, 2, 0 };

    isheap(array, 5, 1);
    withdraw();
    return 0;
}


bool isheap(int arr[], int n, int i)
{   
    if (n * i == 100) 
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}  



void withdraw()
{
    if (isheap) {
        cout << "YES";
    }
    else {
        cout << "NO";
    }
}```
````

Comment: После isheap надо скобочки поставить чтобы был именно вызов функции. Вот так: isheap()

Comment: Забавно, второй раз за утро... Вы проверяете, не нулевой ли указатель на функцию :), а не результат вызова. Пишите не `if (isheap)`, а `if (isheap(...))`, где вместо троеточия — необходимые аргументы...

Comment: Стоит перестать игнорировать предупреждения компилятора.

Answer (score 1):

Самая простая переделка вашего кода —

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isheap(int arr[], int n, int i);
void withdraw(int arr[], int n, int i);
int main()
{
    int array[] = { 1, 0, 1, 2, 0 };
    withdraw(array, 5, 1);
    return 0;
}
bool isheap(int arr[], int n, int i)
{   
    if (n * i == 100) return true;
    else              return false;
}  

void withdraw(int arr[], int n, int i)
{
    if (isheap(arr, n, i)) {
        cout << "YES";
    }
    else {
        cout << "NO";
    }
}
```

Только непонятно, что вы делаете в своей функции `isheap()` и зачем ей передается массив...